# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My demo does not run well.

https://github.com/jiexishede/react-redux-demo01

The error is :

[image]

I don't know how to solve this error. 
The error stops me more than two hours.
I have to ask someone help me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your action below does not contain a `type` property which is required

```
export function loadArticles() {
  return {
    types:[LOAD_ARTICLES, LOAD_ARTICLES_SUCCESS, LOAD_ARTICLES_ERROR],
    url:'./api/articles.json',
  };
}
```

You should modify the above code so that your action creator returns a `type`

```
export function loadArticles() {
  return {
    type: LOAD_ARTICLES,
    url:'./api/articles.json',
  };
}
```

Comment: You are right.                                 ` if(loading){
      return <p className="message">Loading....</p>
    }
`                                                                      Now,  this code is not work.

Comment: I write ` console.log` in the ` render`. It  `console.log`  one time.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an async Redux library for your types, the syntax is `types: [start_action, success_action, error_action]`. See http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html for more info on async vs synchronous actions in relation to "type" syntax. In some places you will want to use `types: [required, optional, optional]` for async functionality, (meaning you'll write `types: required_action_name` and it will look weird because it's a keyword types with a singular type paired to it), but other places in your code you will use `type: only_action` for synchronous actions. Hope this helps.

Comment: For further reading, here is the types: [ ] library I was talking about. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async You can use that library to get 3 types of actions into the output of a single function in your actions file.